# Failed http request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, httprequest

I have an heavy app where everything is in ajax .

Now sometime there is 10+ ajax request when a page loads and some of them randomly fail for an unknown reason to me .

Is there anyway to know why those requests failed ?

I can catch the error inside the error: {} case , should i call the Ajax function again in case of a failure or its not a good idea (avoiding loops) ?

This is the Ajax function that i use to process all my requests :

```
function ajax(aurl,dataType,requestData,successListener,compelteListener,errorListener,async) {

var $xhr=null;
async = typeof async !== 'undefined' ? async : true;

if($.ajax) {
    $xhr=$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url : aurl,
        async : async,
        dataType : dataType,
        data:requestData,
        success: function(response){
            checkAjaxResponse(null,response,successListener,errorListener);
        },
        complete:compelteListener,
        error:function(response){
            checkAjaxResponse(null,response,errorListener);
        }
    });
}else {
    alert("jquery not found ..");
}
return $xhr;
```

}

**Update 1 :**

If i do a console.log on response inside the error , i get the following :

```
  {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

**Update 2:**

Looking at the apache log i see a lot of :

```
[notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

I also modified my ajax request to :

```
error:function(response){
 ajax(aurl,dataType,requestData,successListener,compelteListener,errorListener,async); 
}
```

But that might crash the system if the Ajax always fails ...

**Update #3**

I think its more of a WAMP issue , because i don't have those error on production .

Anyway thank you all for your effort !

Comment: Whats the response say if you inspect using chrome or fiddler?

Comment: Is the requested url is in same domain?

Comment: @cgatian updated the question and yes anoop its on the same domain.

Comment: If you click on the `[+]` icon you'll get further details about failed connections, including the HTTP status code.

Comment: When i click on the [+] i only see : Header / Post  & Cookies , there is no Response(HTML/JSON) or any other info . @ÁlvaroG.Vicario updated the q.

Comment: Is there any console error?(in browser)

Comment: @anoop : no error at all , only failed http request , if i refresh the error is gone and its random .

Comment: @Tarek can you post your response headers?

Comment: @Jaitsu i'm not getting any response , only the one posted in my question when i'm in error mode .

Comment: @Tarek there's no response headers? I've seen firebug sometimes say its a 404 but its because the response type is incorrect

Comment: @Jaitsu : only this is returned {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"} and as i mentioned its a random error . it works 7/10

Comment: Check your server log. It should contain plenty of information about failed responses.

Comment: @Bergi I See a lot of : Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to Apache on windows for an unknown reasons server crashed randomly .

I found some  info related to stack on the httpd (1mb windows default vs 8mb default on linux)

Our production was linux and dev on windows .

Modified the function to the following :

```
error:function(response){
                counter++;
                checkAjaxResponse(null,response,errorListener);
                if(counter > 5) {
                    jAlert(get_label('technical_error') + '<br><br>' + get_label('function_called')+ aurl,get_label('attention_loading')); 
                    setLoading(false);  
                } else {
                   return ajax(aurl,dataType,requestData,successListener,compelteListener,errorListener,async,counter);
                }
            }
```